# select2 trigger change debug

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I am trying to insert dynamic values into `select2.full.js` version `4.0.1` but it doesn't work.

I did

```
var dest = '36,32'
$('#edit-dest').val(dest.toString().split(',')).trigger('change.select2');
```

But the trigger doesn't work - or rather does nothing to my select2 with no console message or anything. How can I debug this?

Html :

```
<select class="form-control" name="edit-dest[]" id="edit-dest" placeholder="search..." required>
</select>
```

Select2 init :

```
$("#edit-dest").select2({
  minimumInputLength: 2,
  multiple: true,
  language: "fr",
  width: '100%'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you separate your select2 init into a different variable, then this should work:

```
$( '#edit-dest' ).val( dest.split( ',' ) ).select2( your_select2_init ).trigger( 'change' );
```

Comment: nope doesn't work :) but thank you for your suggestion anyway

Comment: OK, some aditional comments: 1) after declaring var dest you missed a semi colon. 2) I misunderstood your question so my answer will help you to change the selected values (when select2 is configured for "multiple" values), but now i see you wanted to add possible selections into the select field... in that case, try $( '#edit-dest' ).html( '<option value"X">text X</option>...' ).select2( your_select2_init ).trigger( 'change' );

Comment: A semi colon is not needed in ecmascript 6, look it up ^^ And it's kinda bad to use `.html()` in select2....

Comment: Didn't knew about the semi colon in ES6 or that this was intended for ES6... anyway, did my suggestion worked or you won't even try it because of the use of html()?

Comment: My options are dynamic and are coming from an ajax request so I can't use `html()` anyway

Comment: I can't see why you can't use it but it's OK; anyway, I suggest you to specify that in your question because maybe not everybody will read all this comments to notice you need it for dynamic content and you may receive other suggestions like mine